# Proving the existence and unicity of a stationary point

Tags: derivatives, optimization, solution-verification, maxima-minima

Last question for today I promise.
I have the function $f(x) = x^3\ln(x) - x$. I have to find its absolute or local max and min, if any.
So I studied the derivative but it's not a function I can properly solve, when imposing it equals to zero. So I thought about proving things in different analytical way. The fact is that I am stuck in certan parts.

So furst of all I have

$$f'(x) = 3x^2\ln(x) + x^2 - 1$$

which is continuous in its domain (the same of $f(x)$). I can see "by hand" that $x = 1$ is a solution of $f'(x) = 0$. The fact is that I want indeed to prove that $x = 1$ is a solution, that is there exist a solution. Then I want to prove it's unique.
And then I would like to show that that solution is indeed $x = 1$.

So I thought about considering $g(x) = f'(x)$ and hence studying in terms of $g(x)$, that is:

$g'(x) = 5x + 6x\ln(x)$, observing that $g'(x) > 0$ for $x > e^{-5/6}$. This means $g(x)$ is increasing for $x = e^{-5/6}$ and consequently $f(x)$ is convex in that same interval.
Since there is a change in the monotonicity of $g(x) = f'(x)$, then $f(x)$ has a minimum (due to how the monotonicity changes) and only one, due to having shown there is only one solution for $g'(x)$, since the solution $x = 0$ is trashed because of Fermat's theorem).

Then I showed there exists only one minimum.

How can I show that this minima is indeed at $x = 1$ without just saying that "it's obvious"?

Comment: one *extrem**um***

Comment: As far as I can see there is no local extremum only one local minimum.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Yes, sorry I miswrote. I meant a local minimum. I got confused in writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second derivative test $f”(1)=5$ is clearly positive and hence the critical point at $x=1$ is a local minimum. BTW there is a much easier way to show that there is only one critical point think about when $3x^2\ln(x)+x^2$ is greater than $1$ and when it is less than $1$.

Comment: The fact is: how to prove that $x = 1$ is the solution of $f'(x) = 0$ withouth "just knowing it"?

Comment: Think about it. If $x>1$ or if $x<1$ then there is no solution (this is very easy to see) so we can only have a solution if $x=1$ and hey it works!